# Prevent immintrin.h from including avx512 headers when compiling without avx512 support

Tags: gcc, g++, intrinsics, avx512

I am compiling without AVX512 support, but I have noticed that  immintrin.h drags in ton of LOC for AVX512 , e.g.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include/avx512fintrin.h
```

I have tried to check if specifying march option helps, but it does not seem to help.

```
cat avx512_include.cpp 
#include <immintrin.h>
int main() {}

g++ -march=core2  -E -P avx512_include.cpp | wc -l
34365

g++ -march=skylake-avx512  -E -P avx512_include.cpp | wc -l
34257
```

I know that I could theoretically hack around my gcc instalation and pray that it will work when I remove all content from avx512 headers , but I am looking for a supported way if there is one.

I have tried to look inside gcc headers to see if there is some macro check to include avx512 headers or not, but they seem to be included unconditionally.

P.S. I tried to find a gcc march tag, could not find any, if somebody knows more appropriate tags beside current please comment

Comment: What's the goal here, just compile times?  You'll still get compile errors from GCC and clang if you try to use `__m512i v = _mm512_set1_ps( 1.0 );` without a `-march=` that implies `-mavx512f`.  [The Effect of Architecture When Using SSE / AVX Intrinisics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55747789) / [What exactly do the gcc compiler switches (-mavx -mavx2 -mavx512f) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71229343) .  Unless you do it in a `__attribute__((target("avx512f")))` function, which is probably why immintrin.h still pull in AVX512 definitions.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, just compile times, if I never use avx512 in my code I would hope I could skip including 10+k LOC of avx512 headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC/clang support `__attribute__((target("avx512f")))` for use of AVX-512 stuff in a file compiled without a `-march=` that implies `-mavx512f`.  So `immintrin.h` still has to pull in AVX512 definitions.

But you'll still get compile errors from GCC and clang if you try to use `__m512i v = _mm512_set1_ps(1.0);` without enabling it.  See

- [The Effect of Architecture When Using SSE / AVX Intrinisics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747789/the-effect-of-architecture-when-using-sse-avx-intrinisics)
- [What exactly do the gcc compiler switches (-mavx -mavx2 -mavx512f) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229343/what-exactly-do-the-gcc-compiler-switches-mavx-mavx2-mavx512f-do)

---

For shorter compile times, perhaps pre-compiled headers could be an option.  Most Linux distros don't do that by default.

Or in projects that won't use AVX-512 at all, yeah you could hack things up so the headers don't get included, or at least don't really get compiled.

Least intrusive might be to define GCC's include-guard macros before the files are included the first time.  GCC's pre-processor will still read through the files, but the compiler proper won't spend any time on them.  By size, avx512fintrin.h and avx512vlintrin.h are the big ones; AMX and VNNI and so on are much smaller headers, so probably only really worth bothering with `avx512*.h`.

```
$ grep --no-filename '#define.*_INCLUDED$' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/include/avx512*
#define _AVX5124FMAPSINTRIN_H_INCLUDED
#define _AVX5124VNNIWINTRIN_H_INCLUDED
#define _AVX512BF16INTRIN_H_INCLUDED
...
```

Maybe redirect this into a `skip-avx512.h`.

However, some later files to define AVX-512 versions of their intrinsics, so lack of definitions for `__mmask8` and so on will break headers like `gfniintrin.h` and `vaesintrin.h` which define AVX-512 intrinsics *and* non-AVX-512 VEX (and legacy-SSE for gfni) intrinsics as well.  You can work around this by adding definitions for the key types involved, or skipping those headers entirely as well.

```
// Some headers aren't exclusively AVX-512 but have some AVX-512 intrinsics
#if 0
 #define _GFNIINTRIN_H_INCLUDED         // SSE / VEX / EVEX intrinsics
 #define __VAESINTRIN_H_INCLUDED        // wider VEX / EVEX versions of AES-NI
 #define _VPCLMULQDQINTRIN_H_INCLUDED   // wider VEX / EVEX versions of pclmul
#else  // keep those headers happy
 // These are the correct definitions for GCC as of 12.2, and highly unlikely to ever change.
 // Not that it should matter except for matching builtins
 typedef long long __m512i __attribute__((vector_size(64),may_alias));  // used in gfniintrin and vaesintrin.h
 typedef char __v64qi __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (64)));  // used in gfniintrin.h
 typedef long long __v8di __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (64)));  // used in vpclmulqdqintrin.h with optimization enabled
 __attribute__((target("avx512f"))) static inline __m512i
   _mm512_setzero_si512(void) { return (__m512i){0}; }  // the real definition is more verbose
 typedef unsigned char __mmask8;      // used in gfniintrin.h
 typedef unsigned short __mmask16;
 typedef unsigned __mmask32;
 typedef unsigned long long __mmask64;
#endif
```

This works with GCC12.2 on my Arch Linux system.  Compiling your empty testcase without optimization:

```
$ uname -a  # x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux, using their binary packages
Linux volta 6.0.10-arch2-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat, 26 Nov 2022 16:51:18 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 12.2.0 (GCC) 

$ perf stat -r 20 gcc -c avx512-included.c   # vanilla, no extra #define stuff
   (average 265 ms on an i7-6700k at 3.9GHz)
$ perf stat -r 20 gcc -c avx512-excluded.c   # with _AVX512 #defines and the typedefs
   (average  98 ms on an i7-6700k at 3.9GHz)
```

With optimization enabled (`-O2 -march=native` on Skylake), it's 295 vs. 79 ms.

With `-O2` without any arch=, it's 322 ms vs. 105 ms.  Perhaps not having to run the `#pragma target()` lines is what makes `-march=` faster.  Defining `_GFNIINTRIN_H_INCLUDED` and the other two bring the faster time down to 95 ms, so apparently those relatively small headers make a big difference.

`-O2` is likely slower to compile more lines because intrinsics that take an immediate are only macros without `#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__`.  (As well as maybe spending some time optimizing even when the functions don't get inlined anywhere.)

---

A more aggressive approach that avoids even preprocessing those lines would be to **make a custom version** of `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/include/immintrin.h` and simply strip out all the `#include` lines for `avx512*` headers, and others like `avxvnniintrin.h`, `amx*`, and `shaintrin.h` that are too new for you to want to use.

The same precautions for VAES, GFNI, and VPCLMUL are necessary if you don't want to skip them entirely.

Maybe call it `"custom_gcc_intrin.h"` and include that instead of `immintrin.h`?  Or call it `immintrin.h` but put it somewhere inside that specific project where it's looked for first as an include path?

---

Don't modify your system copy of `immintrin.h` or set things up so a modified version is used by default; that will probably bite you at some point in the future when you try to compile something that does have AVX-512 code paths with runtime detection.  You'll be super confused why your GCC is broken if you forget about this modification years ago.

Comment: __attribute__((target("avx512f"))) stuff is quite unfortunate :)